# How to check multiple columns in a row? using Coded Ui?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

In Coded UI, I am trying to check multiple column data in a row and get that row index of that table. For that i write Linq query

```
 var ro = from r in tblLegalResult.Rows.Select(x => x as HtmlCell) where  r.GetProperty("InnertText").ToString().Contains("TDDSFR") && r.GetProperty("InnertText").ToString().Contains("7/29/2005") && r.GetProperty("InnertText").ToString().Contains("2005072900313") select r;
```

but it is showing empty, can we get the row index like the above Linq query?

Answer (score 0):

Couple things are going on here:

- First, it looks like you're casting a row to a cell. Why is that?
- Second, you'll be able to get the index of any row. I can't remember if the row object will have that, but if it doesn't any cell within the row will have its coordinates in the table.

You can do foreach or for loops to parse through every element in a row. If you're worried about indices you should just use for loops right now. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblLegalResult.RowCount; i++) {
    //Be sure you're skipping the header row if you need to for the test
    var row = tblLegalResult.Rows[i];
    for (int j =0; j < row.ColumnCount; i++) {
        //Test each cell here using your indices
    }
}
```